# ViewPager with the dots only beginning on the third slide (3/3)

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments

I've a ViewPager, with dots, and it's only beginning on the third slide [3/3].
But sometimes, the second slide is not showed in the ViewPager. I tried to use the Log, to show the initial position and the current position, when the position changes, and the result was: the second option is not showed, only the first and the third.

The resume of the hierarchy of my class is:

```
HelpHomeFragment extends BaseFragment {
    ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {}
    HelpFrag1 extends Fragment {}
    HelpFrag2 extends Fragment {}
    HelpFrag3 extends Fragment {}
}
```

and my code is below:

> **HelpHomeFragment.java**

```
public class HelpHomeFragment extends BaseFragment {
    @BindView(R.id.llt_help_tipsbase)
    LinearLayout llTips;

    @BindView(R.id.vpg_help)
    ViewPager viewPager;

    @BindView(R.id.slider_dots)
    LinearLayout sliderDotspanel;

    private int dotscount;
    private ImageView[] dots;
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "Title";
    private DataManager dm;
    private HelpHomeFragmentPresenter<HelpHomeFragment> presenter;
    private ListHelpsAdapter listHelpsAdapter;
    private MyTimerTask mtt;

    public static Fragment newInstance(String title) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, title);
        Fragment fragment = new HelpHomeFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        dm = ((MvpApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getDataManager();
        presenter = new HelpHomeFragmentPresenter<>(dm);
        presenter.onAttach(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        showSlideshowTips();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_help_home, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void showSlideshowTips() {
        configSlideshow();
    }

    @Override
    public void configSlideshow() {
        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getContext());
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

        dotscount = viewPagerAdapter.getCount();
        dots = new ImageView[dotscount];
        for (int i = 0; i < dotscount; i++) {
            dots[i] = new ImageView(getContext());
            dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getBaseActivity(), R.drawable.nonactive_dot));

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            params.setMargins(8, 0, 8, 0);
            sliderDotspanel.addView(dots[i], params);
        }

        dots[0].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getBaseActivity(), R.drawable.active_dot));
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                for (int i = 0; i < dotscount; i++)
                    dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getBaseActivity(), R.drawable.nonactive_dot));
                dots[position].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getBaseActivity(), R.drawable.active_dot));
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

        try {
            mtt = new MyTimerTask();
            new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(mtt, 4500, 9000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //  CUSTOM TIMER
    class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                getBaseActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                    } else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                    } else {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    //    CUSTOM PAGE ADAPTER
    class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        private Context context;
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        Fragment[] fragments = {new HelpFrag1(), new HelpFrag2(), new HelpFrag3()};

        public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragments.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == object;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = null;

            if (layoutInflater != null) {
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
                try {
                    View finalView = view;
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                             .replace(finalView.getId(), fragments[position], "findThisFragment")
                             .addToBackStack(null).commit());
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 
            ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
            vp.addView(view, 0);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
            View view = (View) object;
            vp.removeView(view);
        }
    }

    //  classes fragment for the slideshow. Each fragment is an slide
    public static class HelpFrag1 extends Fragment {
        public HelpFrag1() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_help_frag1, container, false);
        }
    }

    //  and more two classes HelpFrag, only changing the end (HelpFrag2 and HelpFrag3)
    //  and changing the layout to fragment_help_frag2 and fragment_help_frag3
}
```

and my layout base of the ViewPager is:

> **fragment_help_home.xml**

```
<!-- another tag -->
      <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                            android:id="@+id/vpg_help"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                            android:paddingTop="4dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                            android:overScrollMode="never" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/slider_dots"
                            android:layout_width="100dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" />

                    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- another tag -->
```

Comment: Why don't you use FragmentStatePagerAdapter? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html

Comment: Because I did not know hahah, I'll see this. Thanks!

Comment: @WallaceBlend.. as tema_man said, you can try FragmentStatePagerAdapter.. though it saved the instance of the fragment .